# autoit create a batch that sends ' type o.txt | clip ' not working

Tags: batch-file, clipboard, autoit, copy

i spent hours on documentation and forums to try and figure this out.

the code runs without an error but the batch script doesn't get executed.

i spared the reader the `#include<*>` part because it's quite verbose.

```
oToClip()
Func oToClip()
    Local $sleep = 250
    Sleep($sleep)
    Local $sFilePath = "%userprofile%\oToClip.bat"
    Sleep($sleep)
    Local $hFileOpen = FileOpen($sFilePath, $FO_APPEND + $FO_CREATEPATH)
    If $hFileOpen = -1 Then
        MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "An error occurred when opening the file.")
    EndIf
    Sleep($sleep)
    FileWriteLine($hFileOpen, "type %userprofile%\o.txt | clip")
    Sleep($sleep)
    FileClose($hFileOpen)
    Sleep($sleep)
    RunWait(@ComSpec & " /c " & $sFilePath)
EndFunc   ;==>oToClip
```

Comment: why don't you try ```$cmd = "ECHO  type %userprofile%\o.txt | clip > otoclip.bat"``` and ```runwait(@ComSpec & " /c " & $CMD)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What’s happening if you use **`' "command" | clip'`**?

```
 'type "%userprofile%\o.txt"|clip'
```

---

```
oToClip()
Func oToClip()
    Local $sleep = 250
    Sleep($sleep)
    Local $sFilePath = "%userprofile%\oToClip.bat"
    Sleep($sleep)
    Local $hFileOpen = FileOpen($sFilePath, $FO_APPEND + $FO_CREATEPATH)
    If $hFileOpen = -1 Then
        MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "An error occurred when opening the file.")
    EndIf
    Sleep($sleep)
    FileWriteLine($hFileOpen, 'type "%userprofile%\o.txt"|clip')
    Sleep($sleep)
    FileClose($hFileOpen)
    Sleep($sleep)
    RunWait(@ComSpec & " /c " & $sFilePath)
EndFunc   ;==>oToClip
```